# How to get the key-value pairs in sortable("serialize");

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I'm able to get the position/order of the portlets using `$(this).sortable("serialize");`.  When I place a portlet from one column to another it shows the updated order of portlets in those 2 columns. This is the updated order from column2 `widget[]=xyz` and for column3 it is `widget[]=pqr&widget[]=hij`

So, my question is how do I get to know that the returned 2 array list is of which columns?
Can I return the key-value pairs for each columns, such as `col3: widget[]=pqr&widget[]=hij`
and `col2 : widget[]=xyz` ?

My present code is:-

```
$( ".column" ).sortable({
      connectWith: ".column",
      handle: ".portlet-header",
      update : function(event, ui) {
        var postData = $(this).sortable("serialize");
        console.log(postData);
      }
    });
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="column" id="col1">

  <div class="portlet" id="widget_abc">
    <div class="portlet-header">Feeds</div>
    <div class="portlet-content" >Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit

    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="portlet" id="widget_def">
    <div class="portlet-header">News</div>
    <div class="portlet-content" >Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
  </div>

</div>

<div class="column" id="col2">

  <div class="portlet" id="widget_hij">
    <div class="portlet-header">Shopping</div>
    <div class="portlet-content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer</div>
  </div>

</div>

<div class="column" id="col3">

  <div class="portlet"  id="widget_xyz">
    <div class="portlet-header">Links</div>
    <div class="portlet-content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit</div>
  </div>

  <div class="portlet"  id="widget_pqr">
    <div class="portlet-header">Images</div>
    <div class="portlet-content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit</div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The prevEvent variable is there to not handle two times the same event.
I haven't had a better idea ...

```
var prevEvent = null;

$( ".column" ).sortable({
      connectWith: ".column",
      handle: ".portlet-header",
      update : function(event, ui) {

          //Have I alredy handled this event?
          if(event.timeStamp == prevEvent){
              return null;
          }

          prevEvent = event.timeStamp;

          $(".column").each(function(){
              console.log($(this).attr('id')+':'+$(this).sortable("serialize"));
          });
      }
});
```

Result:

```
col1:widget[]=def&widget[]=abc 
col2:widget[]=hij 
col3:widget[]=xyz&widget[]=pqr
```

Comment: It works thanks a ton.  I have a query what's the use of `if(event.timeStamp == prevEvent){
              return null;
          }

          prevEvent = event.timeStamp;`

Comment: The event is fired two times and then I use timestamp to see if I've already handled it. I hope I made myself clear.